# Twitter handles for artists/bands/movie stars etc

Tags: data-request, social-media

I need to find a dataset of the twitter handles for as many artists, bands and movie stars as I can find. These twitter accounts do not have to be super famous. The most important thing is just that I can obtain the handles. Associated with the handles should be the name of the artist/band. For instance, it could be 'Justin Bieber = @justinbieber'. Does anyone know of a dataset like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikidata contains about 90 000 entries with [Twitter username](http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P2002).
Also, Wikidata contains about 130 000 entries with [MusicBrainz artist ID](http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P434).
Intersecting these sets, one could retrieve about 17 000 twitter accounts of artists, bands etc.

```
SELECT ?agent ?agent_name ?twitter_username ?twitter WHERE {
    ?agent wdt:P2002 ?twitter_username .
    ?agent wdt:P434 ?musicbrainz_id .
    ?agent rdfs:label ?agent_name .
    BIND (IRI(CONCAT('https://twitter.com/', ?twitter_username)) AS ?twitter)  
    FILTER (lang(?agent_name) = 'en')
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fagent%20%3Fagent_name%20%3Ftwitter_username%20%3Ftwitter%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP2002%20%3Ftwitter_username%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP434%20%3Fmusicbrainz_id%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fagent%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fagent_name%20.%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%20(IRI(CONCAT(%27https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2F%27%2C%20%3Ftwitter_username))%20AS%20%3Ftwitter)%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Fagent_name)%20%3D%20%27en%27)%0A%7D)

**Related queries**

- Authors ([wd:Q482980](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q482980)) [with Twitter account](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fagent%20%3Fagent_name%20%3Ftwitter_username%20%3Ftwitter%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP2002%20%3Ftwitter_username%20.%0A%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP106%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ482980%20.%0A%20%3Fagent%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fagent_name%20.%0A%20BIND%20(IRI(CONCAT('https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2F'%2C%20%3Ftwitter_username))%20AS%20%3Ftwitter)%20%0A%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Fagent_name)%20%3D%20'en')%0A%7D): 20 000 results.
- Actors ([wd:33999](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q33999)) [with Twitter account](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fagent%20%3Fagent_name%20%3Ftwitter_username%20%3Ftwitter%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP2002%20%3Ftwitter_username%20.%0A%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP106%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ33999%20.%0A%20%3Fagent%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fagent_name%20.%0A%20BIND%20(IRI(CONCAT('https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2F'%2C%20%3Ftwitter_username))%20AS%20%3Ftwitter)%20%0A%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Fagent_name)%20%3D%20'en')%0A%7D): 23 000 results.
- Entities with IMDb ID ([wdt:P345](http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P345)) and [with Twitter account](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fagent%20%3Fagent_name%20%3Ftwitter_username%20%3Ftwitter%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP2002%20%3Ftwitter_username%20.%0A%20%3Fagent%20wdt%3AP345%20%3Fimdb_id%20.%0A%20%3Fagent%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fagent_name%20.%0A%20BIND%20(IRI(CONCAT('https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2F'%2C%20%3Ftwitter_username))%20AS%20%3Ftwitter)%20%0A%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Fagent_name)%20%3D%20'en')%0A%7D): 18 000 results.

Comment: This sounds perfect! Is there something similar to MusicBrainz for authors/movie actors?

Comment: @pir, I have updated my answer.